# Why is SQLite trying to use form entry as a column name?

Tags: python, forms, sqlite, wtforms

I've only been programming for a few months so please forgive me if this is obvious.

I have an issue where I have a local website built with wtforms, and I'm trying to do something simple like take the form data and add it to an existing local db.

I keep getting an error when I test the form. It seems like sqlite is trying to use the `form.field.data entry` as a column name. Can someone please tell me how to fix this?
Code follows:

```
 if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():

    name = form.Name.data
    street = form.StreetAddress.data
    city = form.City.data
    zipcode = str(form.Zip.data)
    bedroom = str(form.Bedroom.data)
    bathroom = str(form.Bathroom.data)
    sqFt = str(form.SqFt.data)
    price = str(form.Price.data)
    typeID = str(form.TypeID.data)
    imageLink = str(form.ImageLink.data)

    command = """INSERT INTO Rentals(ID,Name,StreetAddress,City,Zip,Bedroom,Bathroom,SqFt,PriceMonth,TypeID,ImageLink) 
    VALUES({e},{f},{g},{h},'{i}','{j}','{k}','{l}','{m}','{n}',{u})
    """.format(e=rental_id, f=name, g=street,h=city, i=zipcode, j=bedroom, k=bathroom, l=sqFt, m=price, n=typeID,u=imageLink)
    cursor.execute(command)
    conn.commit()
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
cursor.execute(command)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: x
127.0.0.1 - - [05/May/2017 08:28:52] "POST /rental_create HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

`x` is what I entered to test the form.

This is one of my first projects, I was having a lot of fun 'till this. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect it may be a quoting issue -- you have some values quoted (i, j, k, l, m, n), but not others (e, f, g, h, u).  Perhaps the database sees an unquoted `x` and assumes it's supposed to be a column name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use a syntax like this:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Log' \
               ' (tmstmp, typ, conid, tel, tel_pb, num_int, num_ext, dur, sip, finished)' \
               ' VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', 
               (msg.tmstmp, msg.typ, msg.conid, msg.tel, msg.tel_pb, msg.num_int, msg.num_ext, msg.dur, msg.sip, msg.finished))
```

see https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html for more examples.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. I still don't know why the original wasn't working but at least I can move on. Much appreciated.

Comment: what variable was set to "x"?  Was it "form.Name.data"!? That would be "f". And "f" has to be a Number - it's not in quotes. And: if my answer solved your problem, please mark it as "answered".

Comment: sorry about that. marked as answered. no variable was set to "x", i had just input "x" into the form when testing it. "x" was the form data pulled from the feild.